# OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error when writing multiple files from Compute Engine to mounted Bucket Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to write multiple files from my Compute Instance to the mounted Bucket Storage and it works for some time (it writes 2 or 3 files) then my script stops with this error: "OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error".

The Bucket Storage is correctly mounted and I granted access for my Compute Engine to write in the storage.

If I write the files on my Compute Engine instance first, then move it to the bucket, it works as well, but I want to write directly in the bucket.

Here's some code that reproduces the error:

```
for file_number in range(10):
  for i in range(1000):
    with open('./bucket_storage/output/file_' + str(file_number) + '.txt', 'a') as output_file:
        output_file.write("Some text")
```

I know that I should open the file before the second for loop, but I want to understand why GCP will throw that error if I do it this way. And also it writes first 3 or 4 files, then it throws that error

Comment: How are you uploading the files to your bucket? You are using the Python tag, but I'm asking as there is no more information about this.

Comment: I added some code that can reproduce the error